# Go vs. return button in iOS keyboard for HTML input forms

Tags: ios, forms, input, uiwebview, keyboard

Managing the iOS keyboard for HTML `<input>` forms (used in `UIWebView`) is well known, i.e. `<input type="tel"></input>` for telephone numbers.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

But I was wondering about the keyboard's blue 'Go' button.
Sometimes the keyboard has a blue **'Go' button**, sometimes the keyboard has a gray **return button**.
Is there any opportunity to control this behavior programmatically?

Comment: Is there actually a way to control this programatically? or does everyone have to rewrite their websites?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Update 2020/2021**

As [Cameron Cobb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67132913/2270880) pointed out,
Safari Mobile supports the new HTML attribute `enterkeyhint` since version 13.7 ~ Sept. 2020 (https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_enterkeyhint).

The following values are possible (https://mixable.blog/ux-improvements-enterkeyhint-to-define-action-label-for-the-keyboard-of-mobile-devices/):

```
<input enterkeyhint="enter">
<input enterkeyhint="done">
<input enterkeyhint="go">
<input enterkeyhint="next">
<input enterkeyhint="previous">
<input enterkeyhint="search">
<input enterkeyhint="send">
```

---

**Original Answer**

Aha...

The 'Go' button is only shown, if the `<input>` tag is inside a `<form>` tag (and the form tag has an `action` attribute).
So, if you access your form elements afterwards with i.e. JavaScript, you can omit `<form>` tags.

**'Go' button**:

```
<form action="..." method="...">
   <input type="text"></input>
</form>
```

[image: iOS 7.1 screenshot of keyboard]

**'return' button**:

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

[image: iOS 7.1 screenshot of keyboard]

Comment: Is there any way to make the GO button show up for a textarea?

Comment: Worth noting that `enterkeyhint` requires a surrounding `form` element to do anything on both Chrome and Safari, and requires an `action` attribute on the form as well on Safari.

Answer (score 19):

The important part is that the `form` tag has an [`action`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) property. (`action="#"` is a noop.)

```
<form>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

[image: return button]

```
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

[image: return button]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems that the behavior changed with the iOS versions. The original post was related to iOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

There is a better and more "straight forward" way of changing the enter button text. Use the attribute `enterkeyhint` in the `input` tag like in the example shown below.

`<input enterkeyhint="go">`

You can find more documentation on the Mozilla site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint).

Comment: Thanks for this great hint!