# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to display the iOS keyboard with a "Go" button?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a hybrid application using IBM Worklight 6.1.

For iOS, how can we display the keyboard with a "Go" button, instead of "return" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Go vs. return button in iOS keyboard for HTML input forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986347/go-vs-return-button-in-ios-keyboard-for-html-input-forms)

> The 'Go' button is only shown, if the `<input>` tag is inside a
>   `<form>` tag. So, if you access your form elements afterwards with
>   i.e. JavaScript, you can omit `<form>` tags.
>
> **'Go' button**:
>
> ```
> <form>
>    <input type="text"></input>
> </form>
> ```
>
> [image: iOS 7.1 screenshot of keyboard]
>
> **return button**:
>
> ```
> <input type="text"></input>
> ```
>
> [image: iOS 7.1 screenshot of keyboard]