# How do you display "Go" instead of "return" in iOS 8 Safari's keyboard

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari

Is there a way to have an input field pull up a keyboard that has the "Go" action button instead of "return" in iOS 8 Safari?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986347/go-vs-return-button-in-ios-keyboard-for-html-input-forms - you should wrap you input in the form tag.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @weicool you also need to add action attribute to form tag