# Change the "go" button text to something custom on the mobile keyboard?

Tags: html, forms, smartphone

When typing in a field on a mobile browser, is it possible to change the go button's text on the mobile keyboard to something else?

I have a field for adding tags, and they are added by entering a comma or pressing enter, but on a mobile phone the user will think that pressing go will submit the form instead of adding the tag.

Comment: *Which* mobile browser? At least in the case of iOS Safari, [this is inferred from the structure of your form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986347/go-vs-return-button-in-ios-keyboard-for-html-input-forms). It is not controlled in any standard way that will apply to all mobile browsers.

Comment: I would like to change it on _all_ mobile browsers.

Comment: There are dozens, if not hundreds of mobile browsers, and like I said this is not controlled on any standard way that will apply to all. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the enterkeyhint attribute. For example:

```
<input type="text" enterkeyhint="done"/>
```

But you can only specify certain values. For more detail see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint)