# How do I add an "ok"-button in a HTML input?

Tags: javascript, html

When I make an input type="search" I only see return at the bottom right of my keyboard, how do I change that to a blue ok-button? I see ok-buttons everywhere a webpage has a search-function. How can I do the same?

Edit: I'm making mobile applications.

[image: Return button:]

[image: Ok button:]

Comment: Do you wan to style `submit` button to `blue color button`?

Comment: What does `I only see return at the bottom right of my keyboard` mean?

Comment: I want to replace the "return"button to "ok" for users know I can search here. (Mobile)

Comment: Yeah your requirement is fine, but what is `return` button in your UI. It would be better if you can post more code and image of your UI

Comment: Do you now see "return" and "ok"?

Comment: Yes now we understood your requirement, you want to change the button label in the mobile keyboard

Comment: Yes! Lol finally

Comment: Maybe keyboard settings would help you better than HTML / CSS / JavaSc ...

Comment: @codeWithMe this post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986347/go-vs-return-button-in-ios-keyboard-for-html-input-forms

Comment: Yes it absolutely did, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is to wrap your `<input>` tag inside a `<form>` tag and it will change to the "Ok" button.

```
<form>
  <input type="button"  value = "Ok" />
</form>
```

Comment: The type couldn't be text it would become an input for the user, this isn't correct. I would just change it to `type=button`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @ARLCode Aye Aye. thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @user5173426, take an upvote bud, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Type is the type of input, it's not for the button `value`. You're looking to do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="okay"/>
```

**For further information:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: I mean in the keyboard when I have <input type="search">

Comment: What do you mean the keyboard? Are you referring to mobile apps?